# ALAssetsLibrary multiple instances vs global instance overhead

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, alassetslibrary, alasset

What is the overhead of allocating multiple `ALAssetsLibrary` instances instead of using one instance to access multiple assets?

And from the opposite direction, is there anything wrong with holding a global `ALAssetsLibrary` instance for general use? It is thread safe?

Comment: Why not use Instruments and find out?

Comment: There may be other issues: threading, library updates, locking, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetimes of objects you get back from a library instance are tied to the lifetime of the library instance. Assets don’t like to hang around longer than their parents. So if we are going to access our assets latter we need to keep a reference to the library that created them around.

The point is that we have to ensure that an instance of `ALAssetsLibrary` is persisted in memory until we make use of `ALAssets` retrieved with it. To ensure this, We have to add a static method to retrieve a shared instance of that class (more or less like a singleton):

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library; 
}
```

So, We can refer to it using `[MyAssetsManager defaultAssetsLibrary]` through my classes and we can use threads `(NSOperations an NSOperationQueues)` without having to use “trick” like `performSelectorOnMainThread`.